# Data Clustering using Machine Learning

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network, cluster-analysis

Anybody used Neural Network approaches for clustering data? Particularly

1. ART Neural Network (Adaptive Resonance Theory) or
2. Kohonen self organizing maps

How are they as compared to k-means or any other distance based clustering Algorithms?

Comment: maybe better places to ask this are http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://metaoptimize.com/qa/

Comment: you may have better luck asking on an AI mailing list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-organizing maps (SOMs) have some internal similarities with K-Means, but also important differences. A SOM actually maps your data from the original data space (usually high-dimensional) onto the map space (usually two-dimensional), while trying to preserve the original data densities and neighborhood relationships. It won't give you directly the clustering, but may help you to visually inspect the data and recognize clusters.

I know too little about ART nets.